# In react.js, updated state values aren't showing in table list( table list use state value )

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just made a table to display customers emails and added functions to remove or add new emails.
but for add function, I saved new email into state(`users`). but it's not showing in email table list. remove function is working great! could you help me to fix this issue?
Just attached my code

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const Admin: NextPage = () => {

  const [users, setUsers] = useState([
    { email: "xxxxx@xxxxx.com" },
    { email: "xxxxx@xxxxx.com"},
  ]);

  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');

  const removeUser = rowEmail => {
    const updatedArray = users.filter((row) => row.email !== rowEmail);
    setUsers(updatedArray);
  }

  const addUser = () => {
    console.log(email);
    const lists = users;
    lists.push({'email' : email});
    setUsers(lists);
  }
  
  return (
    <>
    <div className="user-user">
      <input type="email" onChange={event => setEmail(event.target.value)} />
      <span onClick={() => addUser()}>Add User</span>
    </div>
    <div className="user-list">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Users</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {users.map((val, key) => {
            return (
              <tr key={key}>
                <td>{val.email}</td>
                <td><span onClick={() => removeUser(val.email)}>Remove</span></td>
              </tr>
            )
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    </>
  );
}
  
export default Admin;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `const lists = users;` does not create a new array. It just creates a new variable that points to the same array. So the `lists.push({'email' : email});` will mutate the state, but in a way that react will not get notice of it.

use

```
const lists = [...users];
```

Comment: one question, why does remove function work?  maybe it same as add function

Comment: @RomanGavrilov your remove function uses `filter` which returns a new array